# Resign UIScrollView as a first responder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I add a custom view to my UIScrollView
How can I make my UIScrollView, respond to scroll events 
Also, there are a few buttons in my customView with should respond on "touch up inside"

```
entry526 = [[_526 alloc] initWithNibName:@"0526" bundle:nil];
        entry526.view.frame = entry526.view.bounds;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:entry526.view];
        self.scrollView.contentSize = entry526.view.frame.size;
        entry526 = nil;
```

UPD:
I have managed to make my ScrollView scroll, but buttons still do not respond. This is how they are presented:

```
UIScrollView
  -UIView
    -UIButton
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "button pressed" events? A UIButton inside a UIScrollView can respond to touch up inside just like any normal button without affecting the scroll events.

Comment: I also have a few buttons in my custom view. I want them to respond on "touch up inside"

Comment: Do you create the buttons in code or in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your scroll view respond to scroll events, you need to set the contentSize property to something larger than the frame of the UIScrollView.

To make your buttons respond to touch up inside, do it like you always would. Link them to an IBAction in Interface Builder or call the addTarget on the button in code.

There are a million examples of both these questions on SO and the web.

Comment: could you please explain in details? I have managed to scroll my scrollview by setting self.scrollView.contentSize, but buttons inside  my custom view do not respond :-(

Comment: do you know how to make a button that is not in a scroll view call a method when it is clicked? Do the exact same thing. The fact that it is in a scroll view is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, I do. But it doesn't work. I'll try to explain again: UIButton is in UIView. UIView is put on UIScrollView. UIButtons do not respond on touches

Comment: @Oleg the fact that the button is on a UIView that is put on a UIScrollView doesn't change how you wire up your button to respond to a click. It's the exact same process as any other button. Is UserInteraction enabled on all views?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled on all views. I know how to wire up a button .-) I'm confused because my button doesn't even show that it is being pressed (no blue background when I touch it)

Comment: If it doesn't show that it is being pressed, then your issue is that you have something covering it (transparent view) or User Interaction is disabled for your button or for one of the parent views of the button.

Comment: Here's a trick. Change the background color on all your views that are transparent to something really bright. Then run it and if you can't see your button any more, that means it is behind a view.

Comment: Now I see the problem: My button is outside of UIViews. How is that possible? And how i can fix that? I have updated my question